# How do you paste linefeeds into mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

In a text editor (notepad) I create text like this

```
=Heading=
* item1
* item2
* item3
```

Then I try to copy and paste that into mediawiki and it turns it into

```
=Heading= * item1 * item2 * item3
```

How do I get mediawiki to STOP removing the end of lines in pre-formatted text?

Comment: Try giving 2 end of lines instead of one? Just a guess...

Comment: Are you sure this happens with MediaWiki only, and not all textareas? Have you tried using a more advanced text editor (e.g. Notepad++), perhaps inspect the type of line endings in your source text?

Comment: I tried several different editors. I tried both Chrome and Firefox. I also tried double linefeeds

Comment: Pasting into gmail or jsfiddle has no problems so this is not a textarea problem it's a mediawiki problem. You can even go to any textarea tutorial and pasting is no problem. Only mediawiki

Comment: I can paste text from Notepad into the edit area in MediaWiki without loosing formatting. Never seen this problem before.

Comment: So then maybe it's a configuration issue. Hence the question. Go to http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Test, sign in. Try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you need to turn off `Show edit toolbar (requires JavaScript)` under `My Preferences->Editing`

With that on copy and paste has issues with linefeeds. With it off the issues go away.

Comment: But then you (obviously) lose the edit toolbar, and have to type wiki markup by hand. I would say my main annoyance with Mediawiki software is that they still don't provide a wysiwyg editor that simply works.

Answer (score 7):

@gman's answer no longer works (using WikiEditor version 0.3.1).

If you are just a wiki editor you actually need to uncheck

```
     Enable navigable table of contents
```

under

```
     My Preferences->Labs features
```

If you are the host of the wiki, you should add this line to your LocalSettings.php file:

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usenavigabletoc'] = 0;
```

This disables the navigation column on the right side of the wiki editor for all users, which seems to be the cause of the line breaks not working properly.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 1.20.4. I paste 1 2 3 on separate lines from Windows notepad but get them in one line in Mediawiki. Any other ideas?